# How to filter log messages correctly in google app engine log viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine

The log viewer doesn't seem to work the way I expect....

When I expand the options and select "logs with minimum severity: Error" I expect to see only log messages with Error or Critical level.

But I'm also seeing some Info and Warning and Debug level messages - but not all messages from each loglevel category - just some.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: can you please post logs, or screenshot? first hunch is log filtering must be based on full text search, and probably these info/warn/debug messages are writing log in such a pattern which is matching the search pattern for error level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Logs viewer always shows the log output of a complete request, not parts of it.

If you filter by minimum severity Error, you'll only see requests with at least one log statement of severity Error, but you'll also see all other log output for that request even if it wasn't logged as Error.

It's usually helpful in debugging to see the log output of a complete request, it gives more context but does make the Logs viewer feel a bit crowded.

Comment: Thanks. I would prefer if it didn't give me context... I wan't to narrow down on particular log entries - I can figure out the context for myself...